# How to create client side self defined rule in yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I want to use reset password functionality in Yii. For that I have 4 fields i.e email, currentPassword, newPassword, newPasswordRepeat.

I have used following rules in my model

```
array('email, currentPassword, newPassword, newPasswordRepeat', 'required'),
       array('newPasswordRepeat', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'newPassword'),
        array('currentPassword', 'equalPasswords'),
```

where `equalPasswords` is my user defined rule which checks whether `currentPassword` password match with my original password or not.

```
public function equalPasswords($currentPassword)
{
    $oDbConnection = Yii::app()->db;
    $oCommand = $oDbConnection->createCommand('SELECT * FROM Superadmin_details where email=:email');
    $oCommand->bindParam(':email', Yii::app()->session['email'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $user=$oCDbDataReader = $oCommand->queryRow();

    if ($user['password'] != $currentPassword)

    $this->addError($currentPassword, 'Old password is incorrect.');
}
```

This rule gives error on server side, i.e when I click on Submit button, page gets reloaded and then error gets displayed.

I want to display error on client side like other errors.

And I have  enabled client side validation in form.

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
      'id'=>'contact-form',
      'enableClientValidation'=>true,

      'clientOptions'=>array(
          'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
      ),
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change

```
$this->addError($currentPassword, 'Old password is incorrect.');
```

to

```
$this->addError('currentPassword', 'Old password is incorrect.');
```

**EDIT:**

Also, you need AJAX validation:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
      'id'=>'contact-form',
      'enableClientValidation'=>true, 'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
      'clientOptions'=>array(
          'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
      ),
)); ?>
```

and in top of your controller action:

```
if (array_key_exists('ajax', $_POST) && $_POST['ajax'] === 'contact-form') {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to extend the CValidator class. Inside there you can override two methods validateAttribute and clientValidateAttribute.  What you need is the second one. **clientValidateAttribute**. Make sure you have enable client side validation.

```
'enableClientValidation'=>true,
```

Sample:

```
class MyValidation extends CValidator
{

protected function validateAttribute($object,$attribute)
{
         //TODO: server side validation
}


public function clientValidateAttribute($object,$attribute)
{
    //TODO: client side javascript
}
}
```